# Instance of Eq with and without Typeclass Constraints

Tags: purescript

Here is an implementation of Eq for my algebraic data type (ADT)

```
data Stateful a =
  Advancing a
  | Stable a
  | Finished a

instance statefulEq :: (Eq a) => Eq (Stateful a)
  where
    eq (Advancing x) (Advancing y) = eq x y
    eq (Stable x) (Stable y) = eq x y
    eq (Finished x) (Finished y) = eq x y
    eq _ _ = false
```

What this says (I hope) is that Stateful has an instance of Eq if its element has an instance of Eq

Is there a way I can change this to allow for second/backup implementation as well? In <s>SudoCode</s> pseudocode:

```
instance statefulEq :: Eq (Stateful a)
  where
    eq (Advancing (Eq x)) (Advancing (Eq y)) = eq x y
    eq (Advancing x) (Advancing y) = true
...
```

A way to say: if the elements have an instance of Eq, use that, otherwise return true.

or if I had some function
`isConstrained :: forall a. TypeClass -> a -> Boolean`

then perhaps

```
instance statefulEq :: Eq (Stateful a)
  where
    eq (Advancing x) (Advancing y)
      | isConstrained Eq x && isConstrained Eq x = eq x y
      | otherwise = true
...
```

Comment: A tiny note: it's "pseudocode", but I like your version much better. :)

Comment: @Julia hehe. Yeah, that was an accident. I fixed it but kept the mistake there (crossed out) because it's kinda funny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot do this, and there is a good reason for it.

You see, the constraints don't exist universally, they have to be "in scope", which basically means imported from a module in which they're defined.

And this means that the `Eq` constraint for your type can be either in scope or not, and your program behavior will depend on whether the constraint is in scope. In plainer terms, adding a seemingly unrelated module import may change your program behavior without any warning.

This sort of "action at a distance" is a big enough source of bugs in practice that Haskell and PureScript explicitly disallow it.

---

Also, a side note: your implementation of `Eq (Stateful a)` is 100% equivalent to the automatically derived one. You could replace the whole thing with:

```
derive instance statefulEq :: Eq a => Eq (Stateful a)
```

Comment: That's a really good point. Hmmm, can I get access to JS's equality? "===" with purescript? "Are these primitives of the same value or do they share the same memory address?" ... that said, I think I'll stick with typeclass constraint, but I'm curious

Comment: Sure, you can get the JS equality with FFI, but I really wouldn't recommend it: except for primitives, JS equality is "by reference", and PureScript makes no guarantees of keeping references in place, so this may randomly fail.